# VBA Access Textbox populate without clicking

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have my textbox populating correctly with the below code. The only problem is, I need the textbox to populate on its own without the user clicking, entering or doing anything.

```
Private Sub Text1106_Click()

Dim Chip As Variant

 Chip = DLookup("ExtMaintChip", "TableDataPave", "[YrRated] = Forms![FormsFormattedPave]![YrRated] And [RdSecNo] = Forms![FormsFormattedPave]![TextRdSecNo]")

If Chip = 0 Then
    Me.Text1106 = 0
ElseIf Chip = 1 Then
    Me.Text1106 = "<10"
ElseIf Chip = 2 Then
    Me.Text1106 = "10-20"
ElseIf Chip = 3 Then
    Me.Text1106 = "20-50"
ElseIf Chip = 4 Then
    Me.Text1106 = "50-80"
ElseIf Chip = 5 Then
    Me.Text1106 = ">80"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Consider the [Form.Current Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/form-current-event-access).  It fires each time a new row becomes the current record.

Comment: Not exactly related, but you may find [Select Case Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/select-case-statement) useful.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on whether you want to populate that text only the first time the form loads, or every time a new record is loaded, in which case you'd want to use the Form_current() event.

To run the code only the first time, you might use something like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
   Text1106_Click()
End Sub
```

Or to run it for every record, like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
   Text1106_Click()
End Sub
```